# Android org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask

When my app download the XML feed from my website sometimes get it and sametimes generate this error:

> 10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token
>   (position:TEXT �������������}[oI...@1:87 in
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@41f3b510) 10-15 12:26:33.295 
>   28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
>   10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio.MyActivity$rss.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:489)
>   10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio.MyActivity$rss.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:472)
>   10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 10-15
>   12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio W/System.err﹕
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 10-15
>   12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio W/System.err﹕
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 10-15
>   12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio W/System.err﹕
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   10-15 12:26:33.295  28032-28372/it.pucillo.sampo.infodisilvio
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

this is the code of my AsyncTask:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(feedUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);

                if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    InputSource xs= new InputSource(is);

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document document = db.parse(xs);
                    elementi = document.getDocumentElement();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return "Executed";
        }
```